# Receiving Type Error Cannot Read 'length' ionic.bundle.js

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, typeerror

I am receiving `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` error on the load of a certain page of my ionic app.

Because this error points to a file in the core, I am clueless as to how to debug this. I have performed breakpoints throughout the controller file and I am unable to pin it down.

The error comes up after the full page has loaded.

Hopefully this picture paints a 1000 words.

[image]

EDIT

I have now tracked this issue to this piece of code.

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/exercise-modal.html', {
  scope: $scope
}).then(function (addExerciseModal) {
  $scope.addExerciseModal = addExerciseModal;
});

// Triggered in the exercise modal to close it
$scope.closeAddExerciseModal = function() {
  $scope.addExerciseModal.hide();
};

// Open the exercise modal
$scope.OpenAddExerciseModal = function() {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(0);
    $scope.addExerciseModal.show();
};
```

However I use this elsewhere in my app and it functions just fine..?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, `slides` is undefined at the time that line is executing.  Look backwards through the source code - a few lines above that you should see something that lets you know what `slides` is expected to be (if you don't already know).

Then look at *how* `slides` is being created/provided, and follow it back to your own code.

Comment: Of course you're not.. but this code is.  And it's likely generating `slides` based on something you're passing it, or some configuration you're giving it etc etc.  That's why I suggest you follow it backwards.